# Use an image name held inside an element - XML/CSS

Tags: css, xml, image

I am making a CSS file for an XML document. I need to insert an image - the filename of which is contained inside an element.

This is part of the xml code I am referring to:

```
<description>
   <text> Club Praia is divided and linked by a foot bridge over the main street which runs 
   through the heart of Praia Da Rocha.</text>
   <image>pria.jpg</image>
</description>
```

Ordinarily, I would use text:after{ content: url(filename.jpg) }, which would work if it was the same one image being used each time. Instead, I need to insert the specific image name (in this one example pria.jpg) held inside the image element tags, into the generated content code.

Is there a way I can do this? (Hope my explanation made sense!!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will probably be possible with [CSS3 named strings](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/WD-css3-content-20030514/#strings). However, this spec is not even halfway finished, so I'd recommend you go with XSLT.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do this using XSLT, but if there is a pure CSS solution, I would love to see it too.